# function in c++ not calculating correct results, but on adding a cout it is giving correct results

Tags: c++, function, opencv, ofstream

```
#include <stdio.h>  // For printf()
#include <cv.h>     // Main OpenCV library.
#include <highgui.h>    // OpenCV functions for files and graphical windows.
#include<ml.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

class imagepro {
    int MOMpq(int p, int q, float xt, float yt, float* x, float* y, int size) {

        float u[size];
        float v[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            u[i] = x[i];
            v[i] = y[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            u[i] = u[i] - xt;
            v[i] = v[i] - yt;

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            u[i] = pow(u[i], p);
            v[i] = pow(v[i], q);
        }
        float mpq = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j <= size; j++) {
            mpq = mpq + (u[j] * v[j]);
        }

        return mpq;
    }
public:

    void getFeatures(Mat img, long double* feat) {

        float x[img.rows * img.cols];
        float y[img.rows * img.cols];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++) {
                int n = (int) img.at<uchar>(i, j);
                if (n == 255) {
                    x[k] = i;
                    y[k] = j;
                    k++;
                }

            }
        }

        //find COG
        float a1 = 0;
        float b1 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            a1 = a1 + x[i];
            b1 = b1 + y[i];
        }
        float arr[2];
        arr[0] = a1 / k;
        arr[1] = b1 / k;
        //find moments
        float m00 = MOMpq(0, 0, arr[0], arr[1], x, y, k);
        float m20 = MOMpq(2, 0, arr[0], arr[1], x, y, k);
        float m02 = MOMpq(0, 2, arr[0], arr[1], x, y, k);
        float m11 = MOMpq(1, 1, arr[0], arr[1], x, y, k);
        float m30 = MOMpq(3, 0, arr[0], arr[1], x, y, k);
        float m03 = MOMpq(0, 3, arr[0], arr[1], x, y, k);
        float m21 = MOMpq(2, 1, arr[0], arr[1], x, y, k);
        float m12 = MOMpq(1, 2, arr[0], arr[1], x, y, k);
        float m22 = MOMpq(2, 2, arr[0], arr[1], x, y, k);
        float m13 = MOMpq(1, 3, arr[0], arr[1], x, y, k);
        float m31 = MOMpq(3, 1, arr[0], arr[1], x, y, k);
        float m04 = MOMpq(0, 4, arr[0], arr[1], x, y, k);
        float m40 = MOMpq(4, 0, arr[0], arr[1], x, y, k);

        //Find Affine moments invariants

        //cout<<m00<<" "<<m20<<" "<<m02<<" "<<m11<<"\n";

        long double I1 = ((m02 * m20) - (m11 * m11)) / (pow(m00, 4));

        long double I2 = ((m30 * m30 * m03 * m03) - (6 * m03 * m30 * m21 * m12)
                + (4 * m30 * (pow(m12, 3))) + (4 * m03 * (pow(m21, 3)))
                - (3 * m21 * m21 * m12 * m12)) / ((long double) pow(m00, 10));

        long double I3 = ((m20 * m21 * m03) - pow(m12, 2)
                - (m11 * m30 * m03 - m21 * m12)
                + (m02 * m12 * m30 - (pow(m21, 2))))
                / ((long double) pow(m00, 7));

        long double I4 = ((long double) pow(m20, 3) * pow(m03, 2)
                - ((long double) 6 * pow(m20, 2) * m11 * m12 * m03)
                - ((long double) 6 * pow(m20, 2) * m02 * m21 * m03)
                + ((long double) 9 * pow(m20, 2) * m02 * pow(m12, 2))
                + ((long double) 12 * m20 * m21 * m03 * pow(m11, 2))
                + ((long double) 6 * m02 * m20 * m30 * m03 * m11)
                - ((long double) 18 * m20 * m02 * m11 * m21 * m12)
                - ((long double) 8 * pow(m11, 3) * m03 * m30)
                - ((long double) 6 * pow(m02, 2) * m20 * m30 * m12)
                + ((long double) 9 * pow(m02, 2) * pow(m21, 2) * m20)
                + ((long double) 12 * m02 * m30 * m12 * pow(m11, 2))
                - ((long double) 6 * m11 * m30 * m21 * pow(m02, 2))
                + ((long double) pow(m02, 3) * pow(m30, 2)))
                / ((long double) pow(m00, 11));

        long double I5 = ((m40 * m04 * m22) + (2 * m22 * m13 * m31)
                - (m40 * pow(m13, 2)) - (m04 * pow(m31, 2)) - pow(m22, 3))
                / pow(m00, 9);

        long double I6 = ((m40 * m04) - (4 * m13 * m31) + (3 * m22 * m22))
                / ((long double) pow(m00, 6));

        //cout<<I1<<" "<<I2<<" "<<I3<<","<<I4<<","<<I5<<","<<I6<<" \n";
        //cout<<"";

        feat[0] = I1;
        feat[1] = I2;
        feat[2] = I3;
        feat[3] = I4;
        feat[4] = I5;
        feat[5] = I6;

    }

};

int main() {

    char* filename = "caps.txt";

    ifstream readFile(filename);
    string line;
    string str = "OCR/EnglishHnd/English/Hnd/";

    ofstream outputFile("features.txt",
            std::ios_base::app);

    if (readFile.is_open()) {

        while (readFile >> line) {
            string location = line;
            long double feat[6];
            Mat im_gray = imread(str + line, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
            Mat img_bw = im_gray > 128;
            threshold(img_bw, img_bw, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);

            resize(img_bw, img_bw, Size(256, 256));

            imagepro obj;
            obj.getFeatures(img_bw, feat);
            //obj=NULL;
            cout << feat[0] << " " << feat[1] << " " << feat[2] << " "
                    << feat[3] << " " << feat[4] << " " << feat[5] <<    "\n";
            cout.flush();
            outputFile << feat[0] << " " << feat[1] << " " << feat[2] << " "
                    << feat[3] << " " << feat[4] << " " << feat[5] << "\n";
            outputFile.flush();

        }
        outputFile.close();
    }

    readFile.close();

    //waitKey(0);
    return 0;

}
```

The values returning same features array say [x,y,z,u,v,w] for a number of images, and this feature array does not correspond to any image. but when I put "`cout<<m00<<" "<<m20<<" "<<m02<<" "<<m11<<"\n";` 
in the function getfeatures() it is giving the correct values.What is happening here?? I am completely lost.. please help..

Comment: Too much code to read, but - wild guess - you are compiling on Release configuration and compiler optimizes out the call to function, which has no side effects and which results are not used anywhere.

Comment: How big are your arrays? You are allocating them on the stack, which could mean that they become to big.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I can't find out what you want to do, and what is not working.

Comment: @Spook, I don't think that the compiler would optimize a function away just like this. It can not know that the function is useless. :)

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), not that wall of mixed-language code.

Comment: Hi, i am reading images which are of size 256*256 whose names are stored in a file called caps.txt, and calculating affine moment invariant features(array of size 6) for each image and storing them in the file features.txt.

Comment: @Devolus if the function has _no side-effects_ and _results are thrown away_, compiler has every reason to optimize it out. And that's precisely the case in the presented code - feat is not used anywhere else after evaluating getFeatures.

Comment: Why do you convert the result calculated in `MOMpq` from `float` to `int` (which is your return type), just to store the result as a `float` (thus reconverting it from `int` to `float`)? That's just nonsense.

Comment: First of all, the function HAS sideeffects because that pointer is passed to it, and the pointer is written to. And second, I don't believe it, until I see an example of a function call being thrown away.

Comment: @Devolus Feel free to try it yourself. Just remember to enable code optimizations (eg. compile in default Release configuration in VS, for instance)

Comment: @Spook, you raised that claim, so you should make the argument. the compiler can optimize away function call in some cases, but this is IMO not such a case. This can be easily tested anyway, by compiling in release mode but include debug symbols. Then you can step into it with a debugger and check if the function gets actually called. Or you could compile it with -S and check the assembly code to see if it is called.

Comment: @Devolus Check my answer, this is the same case as in cited code. By the way, if adding printing functions solves the problem, I'm 99% sure, that code optimizations are the cause.

Comment: @Spook, if the behaviour changes because of added unrelated code (in this case the cout) it is in 99% a stack corruption issue in my experience.

Comment: @Devolus A stack corruption caused by what? All local variables fit within the default stack size (1 Mb). And how can you explain, that adding print statements solves the problem as well?

Comment: @spook i am still wondering why adding print statements solved the problem?

Comment: @VikasGautam Please read my updated answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to allocate `x[]` and `y[]` dynamically instead of allocating it on the stack. AFAIK you have a about 500k allocated if your image is `256x256*2*sizeof(float)`

Don't forget to free the memory after you are done.

Since the function doesn't use the array after it is done, you could also allocate it globally or statically only once, so you don't need to allocate and free it several times.

**updated**

A quick and dirty way to solve your problem would be this:

```
 void getFeatures(Mat img, long double* feat, float *x, float *y)
 {
    int k = 0;
   ...
    a = x[n];
}

main()
{
    float *x = new float[256*256];
    float *y = new float[256*256];

    while()
    {
        obj.getFeatures(img_bw, feat, x, y);
    }

delete [] x;
delete [] y;
 }
```

However if this class is reused, you should consider adding a constractur where you can pass in the size or the image and which allocates the memory and deallocate it in the destructor. The above way is not really safe, because you don't check the size of the memory and so on, so this hould be handled in the class itself IMO.

From your example above this code assumes that the size of the memory stays always the same for all images, and it doesn't get used. if this assumption changes, this code will break of course.

Comment: Thank you very much. After defining the arrays X and Y globally and private to class imagepro the code is working fine.
I am still new to c++ can you tell me how can i free memory allocated to a array after use. thanks again :)

Comment: You can freely allocate statically 500k. Please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774(v=vs.85).aspx - `The default stack reservation size used by the linker is 1 MB.`. The solution is right, but the cause is wrong.

Comment: without seeing what the compiler actually generated you can not reliably know. You should also refer to Stefan`s comments in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Vikas, just change the return type of the getfeatures method from 'int' to 'float'.
While returning like 'return mpq', you convert a float to int which is then again converted to float, so rounding occurs in between.